# React Higher Order Components: Can I pass JSX elements as props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I am working on a chat application as a project for my resume. I have separate mobile and Desktop "views" so that the application is responsive and somewhat pleasant to use on mobile (in the future I am looking to use react-native to bypass this...). I am using a higher-order component and I have some shared JSX among the wrapped components. Is it ok to pass this shared JSX as a prop through the higher-order component and then render the JSX in the wrapped components; I know this works but I want to know, is it a bad practice?

My higher-order component:

```js
export function ChatBridge(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        currentChatId: null,
      };
    }

    openChat = (id, title) => {
      console.log(title);
      this.setState({
        currentChatId: id,
      });
      this.props.chatOpened();
    };

    closeChat = () => {
      this.setState({
        currentChatId: null,
      });
      console.log(this.props.toggleNav);
      this.props.chatClosed();
    };

    render() {
      const chat = (
        <Chat
          id={this.state.currentChatId}
          icon={this.props.mobile}
          iconClick={this.closeChat}
        />
      );

      const chatMenu = (
        <ChatMenu
          title="Chat Menu"
          openChat={this.openChat}
          currentChatId={this.state.currentChatId}
          toggleNav={this.props.toggleNav}
        />
      );

      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          chat={chat}
          chatMenu={chatMenu}
          currentChatId={this.state.currentChatId}
          {...this.props}
        />
      );
    }
  };
}
```

The Wrapped Components:

```js
function ChatParent(props) {
  return props.currentChatId === null ? props.chatMenu : props.chat;
}
```

```js
function ChatParent(props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid.Column>{props.chatMenu}</Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>{props.chat}</Grid.Column>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not striking me as majorly wrong, but I think there is the potential for unnecessary re-rendering due to `chat` and `chatMenu` being re-created on every re-render of `ChatBridge`

Comment: My instinct is to invert the situation -- basically pass the wrapped components as a `render` prop to a `ChatBridge`.  I might write up an answer tomorrow but my brain is kinda fried right now.

Comment: Yes I am thinking about cloning the child elements within the chat bridge function and just adding the shared properties on the elements. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm looking at this again.  One option is that `ChatBridge` just generates the props rather than creating `Chat` and `ChatMenu` instances, which provides greater flexibility for your  Wrapped Components (though it might not be needed).  It could be a hook.  `function ChatParent() { const {chatProps, menuProps, chatId} = useChatBridge();  return chatId ? <Chat {...chatProps} /> : <ChatMenu {...menuProps} />; }`
}

Comment: But overall I think that what you've posted here is fine.

Comment: That's actually a really good idea I think changing it to a hook is my best bet thank you.